# Trigger this action with keyboard Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers, keyboard

so i have a tiny function to slide and hide the footer and another elements within, both .click functions work well but im not getting keyboard response, my questions, is there a way to trigger the same function without having to repeat it using the .click event and the keyboard trigger at the same time?

```
$(function () { 
        $("#downmenu").click(function(){
            $("#filo").slideToggle("fast");
            $("#downmenu").css("display", "none");
            $("#upmenu").css("display", "block");
        });
        $("#upmenu").click(function(){
            $("#filo").slideToggle("fast");
            $("#downmenu").css("display", "block");
            $("#upmenu").css("display", "none");
        });
        if ((event.keyCode == 40)) {
            $("#filo").slideToggle("fast");
            $("#downmenu").css("display", "none");
            $("#upmenu").css("display", "block");                   
        } else if ((event.keyCode == 38)) {
            $("#filo").slideToggle("fast");
            $("#downmenu").css("display", "block");
            $("#upmenu").css("display", "none");
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function f1(){
     $("#filo").slideToggle("fast");
     $("#downmenu").css("display", "none");
     $("#upmenu").css("display", "block");
}

function f2(){
    $("#filo").slideToggle("fast");
    $("#downmenu").css("display", "block");
    $("#upmenu").css("display", "none");
}

$(function(){
    $("#downmenu").click(function(){
        f1();
    });
    $( "body" ).keypress(function( event ) {
      if ( event.which == 40 ) {
        f1();
    }    
    });

     $("#upmenu").click(function(){
        f2();
     });

     $( "body" ).keypress(function( event ) {
        if ( event.which == 38 ) {
          f2();
        }    
    });

}
```

Comment: thank you! this is a similar approach to the one i finally did.